# Why not post request throw error when request body check fail

Tags: java, spring-boot

here is a post request with request body check. However, request body check failed, just return 400 code, no error throw. but get request can throw error when param check failed. (see the last picture)

here is controller:

```java
package com.example.demo.controller;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Validated
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<String> getUser(@RequestParam @NotBlank String name) {
        return Mono.just(name);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<String> createUser(@RequestBody @Validated UserCreate userCreate) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return Mono.just(userCreate.toString());
    }

}
```

here is request body definition:

```java
package com.example.demo2.controller;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Max;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserCreate {
    @NotBlank(message = "name不允许为空")
    private String name;

    @Max(value = 10, message = "age不超过10")
    private Integer age;
}
```

when I use postman launch post request with wrong request body, just return 400 code, no error throwing:

[image]

but get request can throw error:

[image]

so why the post request can not throw error like the get request? Here is any wrong with my code?

my springboot version is: v3.2.4

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why are you using `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` instead of `jakarta.validation.Valid`? I don't think those work together, if you're using the Jakarta constraints

Comment: @QBrute Both of them are the same effect. I think I have understand it. In Global Exception, I can catch this Exception by intercepting WebExchangeBindException type in webflux (MethodArgumentNotValidException type  in spring mvc).